# Как получить данные из определённой ячейки в google sheets?

Tags: парсер, google-spreadsheet

Вопрос на этом не заканчивается. В общем, имеется Google Sheets таблица с расписанием, которая постоянно меняется, меняется в том смысле, что:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например на картинке сверху видите, что КИТ-ИССС-23-1-17 студентов стоит на 92 столбце, а на следующем листе(день) уже на другом, на 101:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итак, в общем вопрос такой, как выбрать именно те данные, которые находятся снизу тех ячеек, которые имеют название Групп, и чтобы каждый раз, программа сама находила эту самую Группу и выводила те данные которые находятся внизу от неё, заканчивая там, где начинается уже другая Группа.

Если имеются уточняющие вопросы, пожалуйста, готов ответить.

Вот типа такого приложения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Строка - не столбец. Показываете картинки - надеетесь на ответ картинкой? Данные выбирать как? Куда?Данные одной ячейки (см. заголовок) или со всех строк группы? Подумайте, почитайте, как правильно задавать вопрос...

Comment: Итак, хорошо. В общем хотелось бы создать приложение, которое позволяет, в зависимости от учебной группы и дня, которую вводит пользователь выводила данные из Google-таблицы о графике учёбы за день.

Нужны данные которые находятся внизу строки, ограничивая её тем, когда начинается другая группа.

Куда выводить данные? В общем хотелось бы получить данные из каждой ячейки на React-Native.
Можете посмотреть какого типа приложение будет.